# What's the difference between fork() and vfork()?

Tags: linux, system-calls, fork

I would like to understand in detail the difference between fork() and vfork(). I was not able to digest the man page completely.

I would also like to clarify one of my colleagues comment "**In current Linux, there is no vfork(), even if you call it, it will internally call fork()**."

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Man pages are usually terse reference documents. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28operating_system%29) is a better place to turn to for conceptual explanations.

Fork duplicates a process: it creates a child process which is almost identical to the parent process (the most obvious difference is that the new process has a different process ID). In particular, fork (conceptually) must copy all the parent process's memory.

As this is rather costly, vfork was invented to handle a common special case where the copy is not necessary. Often, the first thing the child process does is to load a new program image, so this is what happens:

```
if (fork()) {
    # parent process …
} else {
    # child process (with a new copy of the process memory)
    execve("/bin/sh", …);  # discard the process memory
}
```

The `execve` call loads a new executable program, and this replaces the process's code and data memory by the code of the new executable and a fresh data memory. So the whole memory copy created by `fork` was all for nothing.

Thus the [`vfork`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/vfork.html) call was invented. It does not make a copy of the memory. Therefore `vfork` is cheap, but it's hard to use since you have to make sure you don't access any of the process's stack or heap space in the child process. Note that even reading could be a problem, because the parent process keeps executing. For example, this code is broken (it may or may not work depending on whether the child or the parent gets a time slice first):

```
if (vfork()) {
    # parent process
    cmd = NULL; # modify the only copy of cmd
} else {
    # child process
    execve("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", cmd, (char*)NULL);  # read the only copy of cmd
}
```

Since the invention of vfork, better optimizations have been invented. Most modern systems, including Linux, use a form of [copy-on-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write), where the pages in the process memory are not copied at the time of the `fork` call, but later when the parent or child first writes to the page. That is, each page starts out as shared, and remains shared until either process writes to that page; the process that writes gets a new physical page (with the same virtual address). Copy-on-write makes vfork mostly useless, since `fork` won't make any copy in the cases where `vfork` would be usable.

Linux does retain vfork. The `fork` system call must still make a copy of the process's virtual memory table, even if it doesn't copy the actual memory; `vfork` doesn't even need to do this. The performance improvement is negligible in most applications.

Comment: Thanks for this brilliant answer.. While doing fork(), the child anyways is going to get a new process ID and its associated Virtual space, then why should it still make a copy of the process's virtual memory table? I am not clear in that part.

Comment: @Sen: `fork` needs to create a separate virtual memory mapping so that subsequent copy-on-write copies affect only one of the two processes.

Comment: are you sure that parent process is running?

Answer (score 2):

The `fork()` and `vfork()` syscalls are different.

The `fork()` syscall generates two identical processes with separate memory.
The `vfork()` syscall generates two processes that share the same memory.

With `vfork()` the parent will wait for the child terminates.
The parent inherites from the variables that the program is sharing.
So after the child was called, all variables modified inside the child will still be modified inside the parent.

For more information click [here](http://www.badprog.com/unix-gnu-linux-system-calls-difference-between-fork-and-vfork)