# Why should a child of a vfork or fork call _exit() instead of exit()?

Tags: c, system-calls, fork, exit

From the man page of `vfork()`:

> vfork() differs from fork() in that
>   the parent is suspended until the
>   child makes a call to execve(2) or
>   _exit(2).  The child shares all memory with its parent, including the stack,
>   until execve() is issued by the child.
>   The  child  must not return from the
>   current function or call exit(), but
>   may call _exit().

Why should the child use an `_exit()` rather than simply calling `exit()`? I hope this is applicable to both `vfork()` and `fork()`.

Comment: if you're interested in an earlier [discussion of ontopic-ness of unix C API calls](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/314/29)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As [seen earlier](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5337/whats-the-difference-between-fork-and-vfork), `vfork` does not allow the child process to access the parent's memory. [`exit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exit.html) is a C library function (that's why it's [often written](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-man-page-mean) as `exit(3)`). It performs various cleanup tasks such as flushing and closing C streams (the files open through functions declared in `stdio.h`) and executing user-specified functions registered with `atexit`. All these tasks involve reading and writing to the process memory.

[`_exit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/_exit.html) exits without cleanup. It's directly a system call (which is why it's written as `_exit(2)`), typically implemented by placing the system call number in a processor register and executing a particular processor instruction (branching to the system call handler). This doesn't need to access the process memory, so it's safe to do after `vfork`.

After `fork`, there is no such restriction: the parent and child process are now completely autonomous.

Comment: __vfork does not allow the child process to access the parent's memory__? But i thought they share the same address space, so the child can access parents address space. Was that understanding wrong?

Comment: __After fork, there is no such restriction: the parent and child process are now completely autonomous.__ Does that mean i can call an __exit()__ from a child of a fork?

Comment: @Sen: The child is not allowed to access the parent's memory. If you try it, it might work, because the kernel will not protect you. But the effect might not be what you intend; for example, if your compiler decides to leave some value in a register, it won't be seen by the parent process.

Comment: @Sen: After a fork, you can do call exit or any other function. *Every* process starts after a fork (on Linux, even the initial process `init` is forked by the kernel).

Answer (score 3):

`exit` do additional cleanup like calling functions registered by `atexit` hence it access data outside copied part. `_exit` performs syscall directly w/out any cleanup except in-kernel.

Comment: ... and it should be noted that fork() does copy everything, so you may be able to call exit(), and you can definitely return from the current function.

Answer (score 3):

You have the child call _exit() to avoid flushing stdio (or other) buffers when the child process exits.  Since the child process constitutes an exact copy of the parent process, the child process still has whatever the parent had in "stdout" or "stderr", the buffers from <stdio.h>.  You can (and will, at inopportune times) get double outputs by calling exit(), one from the child process' atexit handlers, and one from the parent, when the buffers in the parent process get full, and get flushed.

I realize the above answer concentrates on stdio.h specifics, but that idea probably carries over to other buffered I/O, just as one of the answers above indicates.

Answer (score 1):

`exit()` :- performs some cleanup task, like closing the i/o streams and many, and then returns to the kernel.
`_exit()` :- directly comes to kernel (do not perform any cleanup task).

`fork()` : both parent and child have different file table, so the change done by child do not affect the environment parameters of parent, and vice versa .

`vfork()` : both parent and child uses the same file table, so the change done by child affects the environment parameters of parent. e.g. some variable `var=10`, now run `var++` by child and then run parent, you can see the effect of `var++` in the output of parent also.

As I said if you use `exit()` in `vfork()` then all the i/o is already closed. So then, even if parent runs correctly, you cant able to get the proper output, because all variables are flushed and all streams are closed.